# Port forwarding for a remote host on local machine

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

Consider the situation where there are three machines

```
Machine 1                  Machine 2                 Machine 3
(Local)                 (Intermediate)                (Server)
(Ubuntu)                    (RHEL)                     (RHEL)
```

I have apache running on `Machine 3` and I need to browse the apache homepage from my Local Machine `(Machine 1)`.

What I have done so far:

I am able to do the port forwarding by using

```
ssh -L8888:localhost:8888 machine2@ip  # on machine 1
ssh -L8888:localhost:80 machine3@ip   # on machine 2
```

I am able to access the apache homepage on my local machine but then I have to carry out the steps again everytime I login.

After a bit of reading, I found that to carry out this automatically, I need to add a `config` file under `~/.ssh`. So I did that on `Machine 1` and `Machine 2` and here is the content of the `config` file.

On Machine 1:

```
Host Machine2
        HostName <Machine2 IP>
        User <username for Machine 2>
        RemoteForward 8888 localhost:8888
```

On Machine 2:

```
Host Machine3
            HostName <Machine3 IP>
            User <username for Machine 3>
            RemoteForward 8888 localhost:80
```

This is not working for me and I am stuck from long on this. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -L8888:localhost:80 machine3@ip   # on machine 2
```

...

```
RemoteForward 8888 localhost:80
```

`-L` alternative in `ssh_config` is `LocalForward`, not the `RemoteForward` as you are using in the attached config.

Comment: In this case, where apache is running on a remote server, which is appropriate - `LocalForward` or `RemoteForward`?

Comment: `LocalForward` does forward **to local** machine. `RemoveForward` does forward **to remove** machine.

Comment: just one last quick question - In a scenario where I wish to redirect all the https request on `Machine 2` (as Machine 2 has Public IP and is accessible to outside world) to `Machine 3's 443 port` the will this work - `ssh -L443:localhost:443 machine3@address` on `Machine 2` ?

Comment: No. You need to use that public ip instead of localhost in your command.